# splice ground wires together in conduit bodies

Tags: grounding, nec

Is it against code to crimp(Bond) ground wires together inside conduit bodies or to extend the ground. a city inspector(Bronx) stated it was not up to code and I'm unable to find any information on the matter.

Comment: Are you talking inside the conduit tubes/pipes or at one of those bends with a removable cover?

Comment: Depends **Which** ground conductor we're talking about. The main one is supposed to be unspliced from the panel to the first grounding electrode, so no splices are allowed. Then it depends how many cubic inches the conduit body is, and what size the ground wires are, if it's in a location where a ground wire splice is permitted. @crip659 **conduit body** is a standard term for the access points, do an image search. They come as 3 kinds of bend, a Tee, and in one end, out the other.

Comment: If your inspector says it's not up to code, then you'll have a really hard time passing inspection, as it's the inspector's approval that's required.  If necessary, ask the inspector what you would need to do to bring it up to code.  Working WITH the inspector is going to be easier in the long run than trying to find some way to wiggle around code requirements, as he/she now knows what your situation is and that it doesn't meet their interpretation of code requirements.  But a picture of the offending splice(es) would be helpful for clarity.

Comment: Are these equipment grounding conductors or grounding electrode conductors, and is the conduit body volume marked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if the conduit body is not marked by its maker with a volume, you can't splice in it *at all.* If it **is** marked with a volume, you have to meet box fill to splice in it. ([Article 314](https://thenecwiki.com/2021/02/article-314/?hilite=article%20314).16(C)(2)) *(slightly confusingly listed as (2.3.2) there but from context that's the designation)*

The Grounding Electrode Conductor is supposed to be un-spliced. There are limited exceptions applicable "if necessary" (which puts you at the inspector's mercy for what's *necessary* rather than *convenient* and the inspector has told you what they think already) and requires that the crimps be irreversible, and specifically listed as grounding and bonding equipment; or that exothermic welding is used. ([Article 250](https://thenecwiki.com/2021/02/article-250/).64(C))

Equipment Grounding Conductors do not fall under 250.64's restriction on splices, so it does matter what ground you mean, here.

It's *possible* that your inspector will approve irreversible listed crimps if used in a suitable junction box, rather than an unmarked or too-small conduit body. You'd have to ask if that might be the case.